# Use circle image view on android

Tags: java, android

I use circle image view on my xml layout but i got this error:

```
Exception Details java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: de/hdodenhof/circleimageview/R$styleable   at 
 de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView.<init>(CircleImageView.java:91)   at 
 de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView.<init>(CircleImageView.java:85)   
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:727)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:858)
at  android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:70)   
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:834)   
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:821) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:518)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
```

I read it official site and do like this site but no work for me.
this is my xml configuration layout and i use like this site:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">

<de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
    android:layout_width="160dp"
    android:layout_height="160dp"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    app:civ_border_width="2dp"
    app:civ_border_color="@color/colorAccent" />
 </RelativeLayout>
```

my gridle:

```
dependencies {
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
 //    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.3.0'
  compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
  compile 'com.android.support:design:23.0.1'
  compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.1.0'
}
```

it does not make my pic circle with a border

Comment: Have you synced gradle?

Comment: yes, I have synced

Comment: have you tried to re-sync grade, and to clean > rebuild > run the app?, I have tried those lines of code on my own and they are working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I check this bit line of code works prefectly fine,I get follwing output from your code:
[image]

```
Option 1: Clean the project or rebuild the project
```

`Option 2: ReSync gradle.`  [image]

```
Option 3: Update your Android Studio.
```

If any of three option does not work, then there is been something error in your styleable file, please check and correct them.

Answer (score -1):

You can make a simple circle with white border and transparent content with shape.

```xml
// res/drawable/circle.xml

<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:innerRadius="0dp"
    android:shape="ring"
    android:thicknessRatio="1.9"
    android:useLevel="false" >
    <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent" />

    <stroke
        android:width="10dp"
        android:color="@android:color/white" />
</shape>
```

Then make a layerlist drawable and put it as background to your imageview.

```xml
// res/drawable/img.xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_launcher"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/circle"/>

</layer-list>
```

and put it as background to your imageview.

```xml
   <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/img"/>
```

You'll have something like that.

[image]

Comment: This doesn't actually solve the problem OP is facing